# Nested if/ and/ or statement excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

Could somebody help with a question I have. I'm stuck with an excel formula. I need an indicator to tell me when something is on target or out of target.

I've attached a screen shot of an example where I have a deadline, the date it was completed and what it should read along with how far I got writing a formula. If somebody could help me I would be grateful.

It should flow like this; if deadline(A2) is before today and date completed (B2) is blank OR/AND if date completed (B2) is more than the deadline (A2) then it is out of target, if not it is in target. Can't get it right so help would be appreciated.

=IF(AND(ISBLANK(B2),A2>TODAY(),OR(B2>A2)),"On Target","Out of Target")

[Excel pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cFkrW.png)

Comment: Your query only needs `OR()` it doesn't require `AND()` & `OR()` both `=IF(OR(A2>TODAY(),B2="",B2>A2),"Out Of Target","On Target")`

Answer (score 0):

So perhaps your logic should be:

```
OR(B2>A2,AND(ISBLANK(B2),A2>TODAY())
```

Based on what you wrote.

So, based on the comment you STILL need the if() statement:

```
=IF(OR(B2>A2,AND(ISBLANK(B2),A2>TODAY()),"On Target","Out of Target")
```

To get it to work. I did assume that suggesting you correct the logic was enough.

Comment: Oh thank you! I've just tried to add the comments I want along with it and it doesn't work;=OR(H2>G2,AND(ISBLANK(H2)),G2>TODAY(),"out of target","on target")... Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you, try, so you may use either of the ways using `IF()` or using `CHOOSE()`

[image]

• Formula used in cell `C2`

```
=CHOOSE((((A2>TODAY())+(B2=""))+(B2>A2))+1,"On Target","Out Of Target")
```

Or,

• Formula used in cell `D2`

```
=IF(OR(OR(A2>TODAY(),B2=""),B2>A2),"Out Of Target","On Target")
```